# Нужна помощь с SQL запросом (пересечение диапазонов чисел)

Tags: mysql

Нужно получить все результаты с пересечением диапазонов чисел - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Например по критериям `от 5000 до 10000` должны попасть все выделенные на стриншоте и отсеяться перечеркнутые. Я себе представляю такую логику `a.start <= b.end AND a.end >= b.start` подскажите пожалуйста как будет выглядеть запрос для MySQL ?

Comment: Картинки, тем более с других сайтов - не приветствуются. Замените ссылку на отформатированную текстовую версию таблицы (ещё лучше - дайте CREATE TABLE таблицы, INSERT INTO данных, и покажите нужный результат). *как будет выглядеть запрос для MySQL ?* Точно так же - любое начало меньше другого кончала. NULL, само собой, заменить на соотв. значение из критериев.

Comment: Я пока заменил ссылку на картинку, думал первый вариант с ссылкой будет более читабельный.

Comment: SELECT * FROM announcements WHERE price_from <= 5000 and price_to >= 10000 дает неверный результат

Comment: *дает неверный результат* Ну так ты же ж два начала (диапазона из записи и диапазона критерия) сравниваешь! и два конца соответственно... с чего бы результату верным быть?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM announcements WHERE (price_from <= 10000 AND price_to >= 5000 ) OR (price_from is null and price_to >= 5000) OR (price_from <= 10000 AND price_to is NULL)` вроде такой запрос решает, но будет ли он адекватным решением для данной ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM announcements 
WHERE COALESCE(price_from, 5000) <= 10000 
  AND COALESCE(price_to, 10000) >= 5000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM announcements
WHERE price_from >= 5000 AND price_from != 2000 AND price_from != 12000 AND price_from IS NULL AND price_to <= 10000 AND price_to != 4000 AND price_to != 15000 AND price_to IS NULL
```

Comment: либо к посту Акина просто добавить то, что не нужно добавлять